# Cycling shorts confusion

Tags: commuter, shorts

Which is better - Shorts with padding for cycling (mountain bike shorts) or inner-shorts with a cotton short over it?

Comment: Better in what way? Comfort? Looks? Ease of having clean kit every day?What sort of bike/saddle and commute do you have?

Comment: Not enough info to answer sorry.   How long are your rides?  Are you predominantly an upright rider position, or more leaning forward and on hands and feet, with the saddle-nose between your legs but no back-side on the saddle?    Are you aiming to ride as fast as possible or more technical courses?  Do you require to "fit the look" of the MTBer?   And one assumption - are you riding the off road or on road ?   Might pay to [edit] in a photo of the kind of item you're referring to.

Comment: Better for you, or better for me?

Comment: While this is opinion based my response would be separates. The reason being if you have padded shorts you need a second pair of pants for cooler days. Personally I wear padded inner-shorts with rip stop nylon trekking shorts or pants depending on the weather.

Comment: A single layer of padded tights is best. You get all the comfort, sweat absorption and padding/protection. Loose shorts are just for people who think that tights look bad for some reason.

Comment: @mikes One needs multiple pairs for frequent washing anyway, that is hardly a problem.